# Aws Athena View column count limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I seem to run into an athena view construction limitation that I cannot find any documentation on it. This is the query I run to generate the View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
)
```

table1 only has 5 rows. If the table1 has 9334 columns, the view construction is successful. But if table1 has 9335 columns, I get the following error:

```
Exception: com.facebook.presto.v217.spi.PrestoException: 1 validation error detected: Value '/* Presto View:
```

Which is followed by a pages-long hash. Does anyone understand what the problem/error is?

Comment: Can you share a little longer error message? I think error reason may be written.

Comment: Unfortunately that is all I got, either via boto3 client or on Athena's query editer. (Which is also why the error is so frustratingly non-informative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that the Glue API only allows the field that stores the view metadata to be 409600 bytes, and when you add that 9335th column it becomes truncated and no longer validates when read back.

What you call "a pages-long hash" is really a base 64 encoded JSON structure containing the internal Presto representation of the view. You can figure out if my hunch is right by checking the size of the encoded string. If it's 409600 then the limit in the Glue API is the problem.

Comment: Interesting perspective. Unfortunately I cannot verify the full length of the hash because boto3 client truncates the StateChangeReason to 32768 (32 KB).
However, I don't think I am involving Glue for this setup? (I am actually deliberately avoiding the Glue Crawler too)

Comment: Yeah.. even though i am not using the crawler, Glue is the system managing the metadata under the hood. What you stated might be it, I am just looking for ways to verify it.

So @Theo, wouldn't this means that Athena View can never express data an order of magnitude larger than Athena Table, given that the metadata limit (410KB) is less than twice of a query length limit (262Kb) to create a table?

Comment: Yes, Glue is really a collection of many services, and tables (and views) are stored in Glue Data Catalog. Views are a bit of a special case because Athena saves the internal Presto representation in the catalog entry, regular tables won't run into this particular limit (if my theory is correct the limit you run into is the size of the `ViewOriginalText` field).

Comment: That looks like what the "'/* Presto View " is this vieworiginaltext.
Do you know where can I find the documentation on this view metadata limit of 409600? I could not seem to find it anywhere?

Comment: Here are the docs that contain the limit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-TableInput